# Create a rounded bar graph with Angular and chartJS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js

I would transform my ordinary bar type chart to a rounded thin bars exactly like the photo bellow

[image: Rounded bars]

I saw many examples suggesting to draw/extend new chart but I don't get how to do it inside angular framework, here's an [example](https://codepen.io/jedtrow/pen/ygRYgo).

Here's my actual graph bar :

```
const ctx = this.myChart.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
this.myChartBis = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: this.labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'test',
      showLine: true,
      lineTension: 0,
      data: this.data,
      fill: false,
      pointBorderColor: '#cd0037',
      pointBackgroundColor: '#ffffff',
      borderColor: [
        '#747678',
      ],
      borderWidth: 0
    }
    ],
  },
  options: {
    showLines: true,
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    tooltips: {
      yPadding: -2,
      xPadding: 10,
      footerMarginTop: 5,
      titleFontColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.0)',
      displayColors: false,
      borderWidth: 1,
      bodyFontSize: 16,
      bodyFontFamily: 'Avenir',
      backgroundColor: '#FFF',
      borderColor: '#d7d7d7',
      bodyFontColor: '#0088ce',
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        display: false,
        gridLines: {
          drawBorder: false
        },
        ticks: {
          maxTicksLimit: 5,
          display: true,
          autoSkip: false,
          min: 0,
          max: 100,
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        display: false,
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          autoSkip: false,
          callback: (value: any) => {
              return value;
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

What I expect is a rounded bars like in the photo with an extra condition : id no value print a grey dot ( but the proiority is to make rounded bars )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use what you have mentioned already https://github.com/jedtrow/Chart.js-Rounded-Bar-Charts. What you need to do is add both files `Chart.roundedBarCharts.js` and `Chart.roundedBarChart.min.js` (just copy them in your project folder, and include them).
Then after you have included this, you can use:

```
var options = {
    cornerRadius: 20,
};
```

For tiny bars like you have on photo you shoul add `barPercentage`, then your code will look like:

```
var options = {
    cornerRadius: 20,
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            barPercentage: 0.4
        }]
    }
};
```

Comment: I get an error message saying that cornerRadius is not a defined option of chart as I mentioned it  ` Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'cornerRadius' does not exist in type 'ChartOptions'`

Comment: Are you sure that files are included? I've tried make chart with this plugin, see https://imgur.com/a/ILmpgVI.

Comment: Are you using angular ?

Comment: It's working but I get this warning message in angular ` Types of property 'options' are incompatible.
    Type '{ 'cornerRadius': number; showLines: true; legend: { display: false; }; responsive: true; maintai...' is not assignable to type 'ChartOptions'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and ''cornerRadius'' does not exist in type 'ChartOptions'.

Answer (score 2):

Angular 7 , chart.js bar chart corner rounded

```
                HTML 
                    <div style="width: 40%">
                        <canvas id="barChart"></canvas>
                    </div>

                .ts

                 chartColors = {
                    red: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                    orange: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
                    yellow: 'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
                    green: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
                    blue: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                    purple: 'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
                    grey: 'rgb(231,233,237)'
                  };

              ngAfterViewInit() {
                this.canvas = document.getElementById('barChart');
                this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
                  Chart.elements.Rectangle.prototype.draw = function() {
                    var ctx = this._chart.ctx;
                    var vm = this._view;
                    var left, right, top, bottom, signX, signY, borderSkipped, radius;
                    var borderWidth = vm.borderWidth;

                    // If radius is less than 0 or is large enough to cause drawing errors a maxhttp://jsfiddle.net/adammoisa/v0dthnyr/7/#
                    //      radius is imposed. If cornerRadius is not defined set it to 0.
                    var cornerRadius = this._chart.config.options.cornerRadius;
                    var fullCornerRadius = this._chart.config.options.fullCornerRadius;
                    var stackedRounded = this._chart.config.options.stackedRounded;
                    var typeOfChart = this._chart.config.type;

                    if (cornerRadius < 0) {
                      cornerRadius = 0;
                    }
                    if (typeof cornerRadius == 'undefined') {
                      cornerRadius = 0;
                    }
                    if (typeof fullCornerRadius == 'undefined') {
                      fullCornerRadius = false;
                    }
                    if (typeof stackedRounded == 'undefined') {
                      stackedRounded = false;
                    }

                    if (!vm.horizontal) {
                      // bar
                      left = vm.x - vm.width / 2;
                      right = vm.x + vm.width / 2;
                      top = vm.y;
                      bottom = vm.base;
                      signX = 1;
                      signY = bottom > top ? 1 : -1;
                      borderSkipped = vm.borderSkipped || 'bottom';
                    } else {
                      // horizontal bar
                      left = vm.base;
                      right = vm.x;
                      top = vm.y - vm.height / 2;
                      bottom = vm.y + vm.height / 2;
                      signX = right > left ? 1 : -1;
                      signY = 1;
                      borderSkipped = vm.borderSkipped || 'left';
                    }

                    // Canvas doesn't allow us to stroke inside the width so we can
                    // adjust the sizes to fit if we're setting a stroke on the line
                    if (borderWidth) {
                      // borderWidth shold be less than bar width and bar height.
                      var barSize = Math.min(Math.abs(left - right), Math.abs(top - bottom));
                      borderWidth = borderWidth > barSize ? barSize : borderWidth;
                      var halfStroke = borderWidth / 2;
                      // Adjust borderWidth when bar top position is near vm.base(zero).
                      var borderLeft = left + (borderSkipped !== 'left' ? halfStroke * signX : 0);
                      var borderRight = right + (borderSkipped !== 'right' ? -halfStroke * signX : 0);
                      var borderTop = top + (borderSkipped !== 'top' ? halfStroke * signY : 0);
                      var borderBottom = bottom + (borderSkipped !== 'bottom' ? -halfStroke * signY : 0);
                      // not become a vertical line?
                      if (borderLeft !== borderRight) {
                        top = borderTop;
                        bottom = borderBottom;
                      }
                      // not become a horizontal line?
                      if (borderTop !== borderBottom) {
                        left = borderLeft;
                        right = borderRight;
                      }
                    }

                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.fillStyle = vm.backgroundColor;
                    ctx.strokeStyle = vm.borderColor;
                    ctx.lineWidth = borderWidth;

                    // Corner points, from bottom-left to bottom-right clockwise
                    // | 1 2 |
                    // | 0 3 |
                    var corners = [
                      [left, bottom],
                      [left, top],
                      [right, top],
                      [right, bottom]
                    ];

                    // Find first (starting) corner with fallback to 'bottom'
                    var borders = ['bottom', 'left', 'top', 'right'];
                    var startCorner = borders.indexOf(borderSkipped, 0);
                    if (startCorner === -1) {
                      startCorner = 0;
                    }

                    function cornerAt(index) {
                      return corners[(startCorner + index) % 4];
                    }

                    // Draw rectangle from 'startCorner'
                    var corner = cornerAt(0);
                    ctx.moveTo(corner[0], corner[1]);


                    var nextCornerId, nextCorner, width, height, x, y;
                    for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
                      corner = cornerAt(i);
                      nextCornerId = i + 1;
                      if (nextCornerId == 4) {
                        nextCornerId = 0
                      }

                      nextCorner = cornerAt(nextCornerId);

                      width = corners[2][0] - corners[1][0];
                      height = corners[0][1] - corners[1][1];
                      x = corners[1][0];
                      y = corners[1][1];

                      var radius = cornerRadius;
                      // Fix radius being too large
                      if (radius > Math.abs(height) / 2) {
                        radius = Math.floor(Math.abs(height) / 2);
                      }
                      if (radius > Math.abs(width) / 2) {
                        radius = Math.floor(Math.abs(width) / 2);
                      }

                      var x_tl, x_tr, y_tl, y_tr, x_bl, x_br, y_bl, y_br;
                      if (height < 0) {
                        // Negative values in a standard bar chart
                        x_tl = x;
                        x_tr = x + width;
                        y_tl = y + height;
                        y_tr = y + height;

                        x_bl = x;
                        x_br = x + width;
                        y_bl = y;
                        y_br = y;

                        // Draw
                        ctx.moveTo(x_bl + radius, y_bl);

                        ctx.lineTo(x_br - radius, y_br);

                        // bottom right
                        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x_br, y_br, x_br, y_br - radius);


                        ctx.lineTo(x_tr, y_tr + radius);

                        // top right
                        fullCornerRadius ? ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x_tr, y_tr, x_tr - radius, y_tr) : ctx.lineTo(x_tr, y_tr, x_tr - radius, y_tr);


                        ctx.lineTo(x_tl + radius, y_tl);

                        // top left
                        fullCornerRadius ? ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x_tl, y_tl, x_tl, y_tl + radius) : ctx.lineTo(x_tl, y_tl, x_tl, y_tl + radius);


                        ctx.lineTo(x_bl, y_bl - radius);

                        //  bottom left
                        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x_bl, y_bl, x_bl + radius, y_bl);

                      } else if (width < 0) {
                        // Negative values in a horizontal bar chart
                        x_tl = x + width;
                        x_tr = x;
                        y_tl = y;
                        y_tr = y;

                        x_bl = x + width;
                        x_br = x;
                        y_bl = y + height;
                        y_br = y + height;

                        // Draw
                        ctx.moveTo(x_bl + radius, y_bl);

                        ctx.lineTo(x_br - radius, y_br);

                        //  Bottom right corner
                        fullCornerRadius ? ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x_br, y_br, x_br, y_br - radius) : ctx.lineTo(x_br, y_br, x_br, y_br - radius);

                        ctx.lineTo(x_tr, y_tr + radius);

                        // top right Corner
                        fullCornerRadius ? ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x_tr, y_tr, x_tr - radius, y_tr) : ctx.lineTo(x_tr, y_tr, x_tr - radius, y_tr);

                        ctx.lineTo(x_tl + radius, y_tl);

                        // top left corner
                        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x_tl, y_tl, x_tl, y_tl + radius);

                        ctx.lineTo(x_bl, y_bl - radius);

                        //  bttom left corner
                        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x_bl, y_bl, x_bl + radius, y_bl);

                      } else {

                        var lastVisible = 0;
                        for (var findLast = 0, findLastTo = this._chart.data.datasets.length; findLast < findLastTo; findLast++) {
                          if (!this._chart.getDatasetMeta(findLast).hidden) {
                            lastVisible = findLast;
                          }
                        }
                        var rounded = this._datasetIndex === lastVisible;

                        if (rounded) {
                          //Positive Value
                          ctx.moveTo(x + radius, y);

                          ctx.lineTo(x + width - radius, y);

                          // top right
                          ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius);


                          ctx.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius);

                          // bottom right
                          if (fullCornerRadius || typeOfChart == 'horizontalBar')
                            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - radius, y + height);
                          else
                            ctx.lineTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - radius, y + height);


                          ctx.lineTo(x + radius, y + height);

                          // bottom left
                          if (fullCornerRadius)
                            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius);
                          else
                            ctx.lineTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius);


                          ctx.lineTo(x, y + radius);

                          // top left
                          if (fullCornerRadius || typeOfChart == 'bar')
                            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
                          else
                            ctx.lineTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
                        } else {
                          ctx.moveTo(x, y);
                          ctx.lineTo(x + width, y);
                          ctx.lineTo(x + width, y + height);
                          ctx.lineTo(x, y + height);
                          ctx.lineTo(x, y);
                        }
                      }

                    }

                    ctx.fill();
                    if (borderWidth) {
                      ctx.stroke();
                    }
                  };

                  /**Chart Data**/
                  var data = {
                    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
                    datasets: [{
                      label: 'data 0',
                      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                      backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                      ],
                      borderWidth: 0
                    }, {
                      label: 'data 1',
                      data: [20, 24, 10, 15, 12, 13],
                      backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',

                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)'

                      ],
                      borderWidth: 0
                    }, {
                      label: 'data 2',
                      data: [20, 30, 30, 20, 14, 20],
                      backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',

                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)'


                      ],
                      borderWidth: 0
                    }]
                  };

                  /**Chart Options - Radius options are here**/
                  var options = {
                    //Border radius; Default: 0; If a negative value is passed, it will overwrite to 0;
                    cornerRadius: 20,
                    //Default: false; if true, this would round all corners of final box;
                    fullCornerRadius: false,
                    //Default: false; if true, this rounds each box in the stack instead of only final box;
                    stackedRounded: false,
                    legend: {
                      display: false
                  },
                    elements: {
                      point: {
                        radius: 25,
                        hoverRadius: 35,
                        pointStyle: 'rectRounded',

                      }
                    },
                    scales: {
                      yAxes: [{
                        gridLines: {
                          display:false
                      },
                        ticks: {
                          beginAtZero: true
                        },
                        stacked: true,
                        radius: 25
                      }],
                      xAxes: [{
                        gridLines: {
                          display:false
                        },
                        ticks: {
                          beginAtZero: true
                        },
                        stacked: true,

                      }]
                    }
                  };

                  /**Generate Chart**/
                  // var ctxBar = document.getElementById("myChart");
                  var myBarChart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: data,
                    options:options
                  });
                 }
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you could provide some explanation to the logic behind your code